# Reading Image from internal memory android gives null pointer exception

Tags: android, image, file, storage

I am quite new to android. I want to save image to internal memory and later retrieve the image from internal memory and load it to image view. I have successfully stored the image in internal memory using the following code :

```
void saveImage() {
    String fileName="image.jpg";
    //File file=new File(fileName);
    try 
    {

       FileOutputStream fOut=openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
       bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

using this code image is saved. But when i try to retrieve the image it gives me error. The code used to retrieve the image is :

```
FileInputStream fin = null;

        ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
        try {
            fin = openFileInput("image.jpg");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            fin.read(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But i get a Null pointer exception.

I checked the file is there in internal memory at path :

/data/data/com.test/files/image.jpg

What am i doing wrong please help me out with this. I have gone through a lot of stack questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because your bytes array is null, instantiate it, and assign size.

```
 byte[] bytes = null;  // you should initialize it with some bytes size like new byte[100]
    try {
        fin.read(bytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Edit 1:** I am not sure but you can do something like

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[fin.available()]
```

**Edit 2 :**  here is a better solution, as you are reading Image,

```
FileInputStream fin = null;

    ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
    try {
        fin = openFileInput("image.jpg");
        if(fin !=null && fin.available() > 0) {
            Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fin) 
            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
         } else {
            //input stream has not much data to convert into  Bitmap
          }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Helped by - Jason Robinson

Comment: The [`available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#available%28%29) method is an estimate. You can find a more reliable byte count using [`File.length()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#length%28%29).

Comment: Wow!!! This was exactly the problem. Thanks mate!! you made my day! I need to refresh the core java concepts! Thanks again!!

Comment: @user1566160 yeah welcome :), please keep in mind what Jason mentioned, I was about to tell you available does not give exact size, it is just an estimate or can be temp solution for small file size.

Comment: @JasonRobinson i knew it, can you please let me know how we can get file length with inputStream?

Comment: @AND_DEV You can't, reliably. Only way to find out with only an `InputStream` is to actually read the contents and see when it stops.

Comment: @JasonRobinson yes that can be a solution to keep checking if inputStream has more to return and bytes has reached to max, so you can reassign a new byte array.
but let me tell you,i have used this available method from last 3 years and never faced any issues as such though even docs says not to use it :)

Comment: I can't speak to how reliable it actually is. Honestly though, since he's reading an image, he should be leveraging [`BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)

Comment: @AND_DEV i have another question like now i am saving jpeg image if i want to save gif image then??? what should i do? can you help me with that?

Comment: @JasonRobinson  thanks that is a good way for creating a btimap. but if you talk about reading text files, there is no such ways we need to do what i mentioned in earlier comments. Anyways thanks :)

Comment: @user1566160 please write new question for that.

Comment: @AND_DEV Yes there is. It's in my first comment. You can get the length (byte size) of a file this way: `new File(filePath).length()`

Comment: if it is a text file in internal storage?